# Electron app failing with cryptic output - Exits with SIGSEGV

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, electron

I'm building this app called [bibiscio](https://github.com/andreafeccomandi/bibisco), but my problem is, I'm getting errors when building the project:

```
/Users/mintstudios/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron exited with signal SIGSEGV
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/mintstudios/Documents/git-inst/bibisco/bibisco/app
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c electron .
```

I don't know what this means, and I've been at this for a while.

System: M1 Mac, ARM architecture, macOS Big Sur

ARM might be the problem though, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04, and this has been reported before on electron's GH page. I made a comment on that [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27086), probably best to continue there.

Comment: I had this issue just now. Issue for me was Node version. I've developed my app on Windows using Node v16.18.0 and tried to run it on Mac using v18.xx.x, after changing the Node version to the same as on Windows (v16.18.0 in my case) it works as expected.